# How to calculate $F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}$ efficiently?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, differential-geometry

The quantity $\frac{1}{2}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}$ is equal to $B^2-E^2$. I can show this pretty laboriously via matrix multiplication, and slightly faster via the index notation. Is there an elegant method of computing this, possibly using the fact that $F$ is a 2-form $F=dA$?

Note: I can do the brute force calculation in components, and I understand how to do that calculation efficiently. I'm looking for a geometric argument ideally because the component makes the result seem surprising.

Comment: But $B$ and $E$ are _defined_ as components of $F$. It's impossible to give a completely component-free proof of an inherently component-based statement. It's like asking for the horizontal distance between two points but strictly forbidding picking any axes. Are you just looking for a cleaner derivation or something?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform do you mean 3-scalars or Lorentz scalars? The latter seems a tautology almost.

Comment: @knzhou they're defined in a particularly nice manner that I thought may have a differential geometry interpretation. It is possible there isn't one though.

Comment: To the moderator that deleted my previous comment: it is weird that you did so, but did not delete OP's repply to it. It gives the impression that I ghosted OP, which is not the case. Not cool...

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I hadn't noticed... was your comment to suggest that it must be of the form $\alpha E^2 + \beta B^2 + \gamma E\cdot B$? Because determining all of those co-efficients seems a reasonably large amount of work a priori.

Comment: @jacob1729 $\vec E\cdot\vec B$ is a pseudo-scalar, so $\gamma=...$. Note also that a simple Lorentz transformation shows that your ansatz is a scalar only if $\beta=-\alpha$, etc.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform the argument for $\gamma=0$ is nice. I'm not sure how to see $\alpha=-\beta$ without doing a matrix multiplication I don't want to do. (That is, until I've computed $F\cdot F$ I don't know $E^2-B^2$ is a Lorentz scalar, so I can't see how to do that bit non circularly.) However that has narrowed it down to 2 4x4 multiplications with only 2 components in each matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no escape, you need to single out time from space-time in order to define $E$ and $B$. If you want to work in terms of $d$ and $A$, you need separate time from space as:

$$
d=\tilde d+dt\partial_{t}\qquad A= \tilde A + A_t dt
$$

Now, the electric field and magnetic field can then be defined as:

$$
E dt=(\partial_{t}\tilde A+\tilde d A_{t})dt\qquad B=\tilde d \tilde A
$$

where $E$ is a $1$-form and $B$ is a $2$-form, both in a $3$-dimensional space. Now you can compute $|F|^{2}=F\wedge * F$ as

$$
|F|^{2}_{d=4}=|(\tilde d+dt\partial_{t})(\tilde A + A_t dt)|^{2}_{d=4}=|B+Edt|^{2}_{d=4} = (|B|^{2}_{d=4}+|Edt|^{2}_{d=4})
$$

where the crossing terms vanish since $B\wedge*Edt=0$.

The reason why  $B\wedge*Edt=0$  is because $*Edt$ will have at least one differential $dx^{i}$ that is also in $B$, so it will vanish since $dx^i\wedge dx^i =0$. Note that there are just 3 spatial differentials $dx^{i}$, $i=1$ to $3$, and both $B$ and $*(Edt)$ are $2$-forms that only depends on spatial differentials.

Reducing $d=4$ to $d=3$, note that $(*B)_{d=4}=(*B)_{d=3}dt$ and $(*Edt)_{d=4}=-(*E)_{d=3}$, so we get:

$$
|B|^{2}_{d=4}=(B\wedge *B)_{d=4} = (B\wedge *B)_{d=3} dt = |B|^{2}_{d=3} dt
$$

$$
|Edt|^{2}_{d=4}= (E\wedge * E)_{d=4} = -(E\wedge * E)_{d=3} dt = -|E|^{2}_{d=3} dt
$$

Note that the minus sign comes from the star product when it hits a time-like differential:

$$
*(dt\wedge dx^{i})=\eta^{t t}\eta^{i_1 j_1} \varepsilon_{t j_1 j_2 j_3} dx^{j_2}\wedge dx^{j_3} = - \varepsilon_{t i_1 j_2 j_3} dx^{j_2}\wedge dx^{j_3}
$$

since $\eta^{tt}=-1$.

Comment: I think there should be a ^2 on the second term in your last equation. This is I think what I was looking for (representation of $F=B+Edt$ along with $B\wedge *Edt=0$) but a lot of it is unfamiliar. Can you expand on why $B\wedge*Edt$=0?

Comment: Also, is there some notational slight of hand where tilded quantities aren't quite the 3d quantities but the 4d ones projected on to 3d space? Otherwise how can $F=B+Edt$ when $B$ is a 3-dimensional 2-form but $F$ is 4d?

Comment: Yes, there are some details about 3d and 4d that I skeep. But it is straightforward since the both $E$ and $B$ just has the 3d differentials.

Comment: I also added the explanation of why $B\wedge*Edt=0$